# Angular router autoguard

Tags: angular

I'm trying to implement router Autoguard but when I redirect the user to other component the canActivate is not executed.

This is the example of my code:

LoginComponent.ts

```
public doLogin(): void {
        const userName: string = this.loginForm.get('username').value;
        const password: string = this.loginForm.get('password').value;


        this.authService.login(userName, password).subscribe((resp) => {
            if ((userName === resp.user) && (password === resp.password)) {
                this.authService.setIsLogged(true);
               // In this case I'm not redirected to the locker/assign and the canActivate is not executed
                this.router.navigate(['locker/assign']); 
            } else {
                this.authService.setIsLogged(false);
            }
        });
    }
```

logged-in.guard.ts

```
canActivate(
        next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot
    ): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
        // Check if the user logged.
        if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
            return true;
        }

        // If not logged redirect the user to login page.
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
    }
```

auth.service.ts

```
public login(user: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(LOGIN_URL + 'login');
    }
```

router configuration:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', redirectTo: 'locker/assign', pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'locker',
        loadChildren: './pages/locker/locker.module#LockerModule',
        canActivate: [ LoggedInGuard ]
    }, {
        path: 'login', component: LoginComponent
    },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'locker/assign', pathMatch: 'full' }  
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

HTML

```
        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                <input matInput placeholder="{{ 'USER' | translate }}" id='username' formControlName="username">
            </mat-form-field>

            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                <input matInput   formControlName="password" type="password">
            </mat-form-field>

            <button  (click)="doLogin()">Login</button>
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: can you share your routing configuration?

Comment: Yes, I have data on the response when I call the login service but the problem is the user is not redirected to the locker/assign

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
return this.router.parseUrl("/admin/login");
```

in your else condition of the `canActivate()`, you don't even need `return false` after that.

Comment: Well, try this article and match with your code: https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-course-router-guards/